# Configuring OpenBSD's PF as a router

Tags: openbsd, pf, gateway

I am running OpenBSD 4.4, I copied the template from https://markshroyer.com/guides/router/ch07.html for `/etc/pf.conf` and edited it to match my network.
When I start it I get syntax errors on only three lines that I didn't need to edit:
`match on $if_wan scrub (reassemble tcp random-id max-mss 1440)`,

`match out on $if_wan from $net_private to !(if_wan) nat-to ($if_wan)`
which I tried editing to `match out on $if_wan from $net_private to !($if_wan) nat-to ($if_wan)`, and

`pass in on $if_lan net photo tcp to port ftp rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 8021`
These are the only lines that claim a syntax error. Anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: OBSD 4.4 is really old and (I believe) the syntax has changed substantially.  I think in this case you're going to have a hard time finding help.  Can you upgrade to 5.8?

Comment: FreeBSD uses [the same version of PF as OpenBSD 4.5](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/firewalls-pf.html) so someone who is versed in FreeBSD's `pf` version might be able to help.

Comment: I should have added that it was for a lab setting, and not for actual deployment. I was only using 4.4 because I found a VM of it. I have since switched to 5.8 and it parses without any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax I was using was for a newer version of PF, and in order to fix it I just upgraded to the latest version of OpenBSD.